# javascript not equal strings check returns true

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having a simple java script function that checks wither a trip type is a safe round trip

```
    function CheckIfSafeRideRoundTrip()
    {
        var comboBox = $find("<%=rcmb_TripType.ClientID%>");
        var selectedTripType = comboBox.get_selectedItem().get_text();
        var isAirportRoundTrip = false;
        if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip");
            isAirportRoundTrip = true;
        return isAirportRoundTrip;

    }
```

the selectedTripType value returns "Round Trip - Airport" but for some why the comparison Boolean expression returns true and sets isAirportRoundTrip to true
rcmb_TripType is a telerik radComboBox which is irrelevant as I made sure of the selectedTripType value through the debugger
as an additional info here's where I call the function

```
    function BuildConfirmationLayout()
    {
        var divOthersAddressInfo = document.getElementById("div_OthersLocationInfo");
        var divAirportAddressInfo = document.getElementById("div_AirPortLocationInfo");
        var divAirportRoundTrip = document.getElementById("div_Airport_SecondTicketDate");
        var divSaferideRoundTrip = document.getElementById("div_SafeRide_Standby");
        var isAirport = CheckIfAirportTrip();
        var isAirportRoundTrip = CheckIfAirportRoundTrip();
        var isSafeRideRoundTrip = CheckIfSafeRideRoundTrip();

        if (isAirport) {
            divOthersAddressInfo.style.display = "none";
            divAirportAddressInfo.style.display = "block";
            divAirportRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
            divSaferideRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            divAirportAddressInfo.style.display = "none";
            divOthersAddressInfo.style.display = "block";
            divAirportRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
            divSaferideRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
        }

        if(isAirportRoundTrip)
        {
            divAirportRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
            divSaferideRoundTrip.style.display = "block";
        }

        if(isSafeRideRoundTrip)
        {
            divAirportRoundTrip.style.display = "none";
            divSaferideRoundTrip.style.display = "block";

        }

    }
```

Comment: There's a simple way of avoiding these kinds of errors: always use curly braces for your `if` statements. See the semicolon in your `CheckIfSafeRideRoundTrip` function. Also, consider learning how the debugger works on your browser of choice and use that to step through your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semi colon after the `if` statement terminates the line, remove that and you should be fine.

```
if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip"); <-- remove this semi colon
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have semicolon after this line:

`if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip");`

It ends `if` statement and next line is always executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip");
```

You have a `;` here.  This is the same as:

```
if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip"){}
```

What you meant to do was:

```
if(selectedTripType == "Safe Ride - Round Trip"){
    isAirportRoundTrip = true;
}
```

(You just need to lose the `;`.  I only added the `{}` for clarity; it's a good idea to *always* have them.)